Adjusted vs Unadjusted Odds Ratio
I am conducting a before-and-after analysis using an Interrupted Time Series (ITS) model.
The outcome of interest is malaria (yes or no), and the intervention occurred on June 11th, 2020 (single intervention).
The dataset spans from 2018 to 2022, with negative time(days) values representing the period before June 11th, 2020, and positive time values representing the period after this intervention.
Additionally, pre_post_i is an indicator variable column where 0 indicates time before June 11th, 2020, and 1 indicates time on or after June 11th, 2020.
The unadjusted odds ratio during the pre-period (before June 11th 2020) is approximately 14.11, and during the post-period (on or after June 11th 2020), it is approximately 16.21.
After fitting the adjusted model, the results are as follows:
β1 (time) = 0.99
β2 (pre_post_i) = 0.97
β3 (interaction term)time*pre_post_i = 1.001

Is it normal to observe adjusted odds ratios of β1 = 0.99, β2 = 0.97, and β3 = 1.001 when the unadjusted odds ratios during the pre and post periods are 14.11 and 16.21, respectively?

Welcome to the site. It would be helpful if you told us what you adjusted for. Also there are other ways to code the time and intervention that you might try.

What do you mean by "during the pre and post periods"?  The variable "prepost_1" wuld not be usable for separate analysis by period (nor would the interaction).. Alos ORs for what were 14.11 and 16.21? Also, measuring time in days might not be best, just in terms of units (maybe adjust to months). How was data collected - daily? Monthly? What data was collected?
